# C++ Declaring functions before variables

Tags: c++, struct

So I'm creating a struct called Person with a couple getter functions in it that return variables declared AFTER they're used in the getter functions.  When I do this in a separate struct there are no errors, but now with this code:

```
struct Person
{
    std::string name() const { return name; }
    std::string address() const { return address; }

    std::string name;
    std::string address;
};
```

I get this error:

```
IntelliSense: no suitable constructor exists to convert from "std::string () const" to "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char>>"
```

In another struct I have this...

```
struct Sales_data
{
    std::string isbn() const { return book_number; }

    std::string book_number;
};
```

and I don't get any errors.  Where did I go wrong and how can I avoid this problem in the future?

Comment: In the working example, change `std::string book_number;` to `std::string isbn;` -  see a pattern? Reverse-apply this knowledge to fix the non-working code.

Comment: Thank you for that wonderful OOOOoohh... moment.  Solved the problem.  Thanks again!

Comment: [OT]: you may return by const reference to avoid copy (i.e. `const std::string& isbn() const { return book_number; }`)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you have used the same name for the member method and member variable in the first example, but different names in the second.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that in the scope of the function `name()`, the identifier `name` refers to the function itself.  So, the function is trying to return itself, and it isn't able to convert a const member function that returns a string and takes no arguments (that is, `std::string () const`) to an `std::string`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two `name`s in the class. Inside `name` the function, the function shadows `name` the variable.

Make them different and all will be ok.

E.g. Change the variable to `m_name`, or change the function to `getName`.

Comment: +1 Another common convention for c++ would be to use `name_` as the variable.

Comment: @red_eight. Thanks for the upvote. Yes using `name_` as the member variable is also a good convention to follow.